# Invalidate cloudfront cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-codepipeline

I want to invaliate cloudfront cache as last build step in codepipeline.
I created lambda function (node):

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
const aws = require('aws-sdk'),
cloudfront = new aws.CloudFront({apiVersion: '2018-06-18'}),
codepipeline = new aws.CodePipeline(),
jobId = event["CodePipeline.job"].id,
paramsCloudFront = {
  DistributionId: 'distr_id',
  InvalidationBatch: {
    CallerReference: `Date.now()`,
    Paths: {
      Quantity: 1,
      Items: ['/*',]
    }
  }
},
putJobSuccess = function(message) {
    var params = {
        jobId: jobId
    };
    codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult(params, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            context.fail(err);      
        } else {
            context.succeed(message);      
        }
    });
},
putJobFailure = function(message) {
    var params = {
        jobId: jobId,
        failureDetails: {
            message: JSON.stringify(message),
            type: 'JobFailed',
            externalExecutionId: context.invokeid
        }
    };
    codepipeline.putJobFailureResult(params, (err, data) => {
        context.fail(message);      
    });
}


cloudfront.createInvalidation(paramsCloudFront, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    putJobFailure(err)
  } else {
    putJobSuccess(data)
  }
});
```

};

Codepipeline reports stage is successful but no invalidation in cloudfront is created. No errors in cloudwatch. 
In IAM I gave full access to cloudfront to both lambda and codepipeline.
What is wrogn?

Comment: `console.log()` is your friend.  Modify your `putJob*` functions or the cloudfront method callback to do some logging.

Comment: thanks, console helped :) it turns out problem was in `Date.now()'. Changed it to Date.now() + ''.